# Block messages from advertisement or organisations (Non-digit sender id)

Tags: 8.0, gdr-2, call-sms-filter

I'm getting messages from organisations or websites who does not have a phone number. I mean messages from TD-MAN, LM-058457 etc. Is there any way to block messages from these sources. I'm from India.

Answer (score 1):

If you own a Nokia you can use the call and sms filter

Go to Settings -> Call & SMS filter

in this app you can select specific numbers that should be blocked and in advanced settings you can also block withheld numbers.

I'm from Europe so don't know if these Indian (non digit sender) sources are easily blocked as well because we don't have them in Europe but it should help you at least a little bit.

some screenshots here:http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/18112_Nokia_adds_call_and_SMS_blocki.php

If you dont have a Nokia phone but HTC, Samsung or any other device there is no option.

Comment: I'm having Lumia 620 with gdr-2 (I specified this in tags). The answer you given is the normal way of blocking a Sender/ Caller. But these non digit sender id can't be blocked in this way. And there's no call log from these sources too.

Comment: as I said in my answer I'm not from India so wasn't sure on how these non digit senders work. I do believe you that this option didn't work for you if you say so. Does blocking withheld numbers work? Also is it possible to block these kinds of numbers on other phones (e.x. iphone/android)?

Comment: I'm able to block normal phone numbers. And I was able to block these kinda sender ids in old Nokia classic phone as `Screened Numbers`.

Comment: Wow this sounds terrible. I'm from South Africa and we don't have this either, though I'm pretty sure we will probably get it as all terrible ideas end up here sooner or later. How is there no call log - does it not even appear as Unknown?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this worked but I think it did. Contact you provider and ask them to block these texts and calls. I did this by text to Vodafone and it seemed to work.